# Пирамидальная сортировка

Tags: алгоритм, сортировка, c++

Я уже день думаю и до сих пор не могу понять, как посчитать `heap_size` в алгоритме пирамидальной сортировки.
Пусть дана функция

```
int max_heapify(std::vector <int> A, int i)
{
int largest;
int l= Left(i);
int r = Right(i);
if (l <= heap_size (A) && A[l] > A[i]) 
    largest = l;
else 
    largest = i;
if (r <= heap_size(A) && A[r] > A[largest])
    largest = r;
if (largest != i)
    {
        int temp = A[i];
        A[i] = A[largest];
        A[largest] = temp; 
        max_heapify(A, largest);
    }
}
```

В этой функции все параметры мне ясны, кроме того, как для заданного массива найти `heap_size`; изввестно только, что он должен быть не больше `A.size`

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что Вы не понимаете и что хотите достичь? Можете переформулировать свою проблему?

Comment: Я хочу понять, как рассчитывать heap_size для произвольного массива.
Для вектора его размер, который в псевдокоде назван `length[A]`, можно посчитать как `A.size`. Я хотел бы иметь простую формулу для рассчёта `heap_size`: ` = A.size` или `A.size - 1` или что-нибудь ещё ясное.